# LNK1104 after tfpt treeclean

Tags: windows, tfs, msbuild, linker-errors

After next routine solution rebuild I got a few linker errors: "LNK1104: cannot open file".

The inputs:

- MSBuild v14.0.25420.1, link.exe v14.00.24215.1
- The file exists
- I can open and change the file
- The console is running under Administrator
- The /m switch used
- TFS

I tried :
 - a full cleanup by running "tfpt treeclean /r"
 - get the latest version with "overwrite all files"
 - running msbuild without /m switch
 - restarting machine

Nothing of that helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that I found accidentally is that some of the files in the output directory were read-only. Files to which linker failed to access were read-only.

Unsetting the attribute has solved the issue.